# Saving <div> styles with its content inside a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, contenteditable

The title of this question might be unclear, but thats why I'm trying to explain it right here. I've got a contenteditable div which acts like a textarea for the articles of my blog (adminpanel). Getting the db data to display properly in the contenteditable div is no problem. But when I save the updated article version to my database, it aint saving the div styles ( as example) which are in the contenteditable div.

**Example:**

```
<div id="article_content" class="edit_article_content_container_inner" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $db_content ?></div>
```

**outputs:**

```
<div id="article_content" class="edit_article_content_container_inner" contenteditable="true">
<div>Dear visitor,</div>
<div><br /></div>
<div>Thank you for visiting</div>
</div>
```

**When I make changes and decide to save the new version, the db_content column gets updated and looks like:**

```
Dear visitor,Thank you for visiting this page
```

So the contenteditable div destroys my div styles when saving the new updated article. Is there a way to still store these div styles?

Thank you.

This is the part where I make the ajax call

```
$("#btn-save-new-article").on('click', function (event) {
        var article_id = $('.edit_article_title_container').attr('data-article-id');
        var article_title = $("#article_title").text();
        var article_content = $("#article_content").text();
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/includes/db-requests/admin/db-save-edited-article.php",
            data: {article_id: article_id, article_title: article_title, article_content: article_content},
            success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){   finish_editing_article(data,textStatus,jqXHR);  }
        });
    });

    function finish_editing_article(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
        //alert (data);
        if (data == "article_edited_success") {
            //location.reload();
            alert(data);
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm storing the article_id, article_title and article_content.

Receiving the data to actual store it:

```
//DIV SUBMITTED DATA
$article_id = safe($mysqli,$_POST['article_id']);
$article_title = safe($mysqli,$_POST['article_title']); 
$article_content = $_POST['article_content'];
```

Comment: How are you saving the info? What is the mechanism?

Comment: I have updated my question with the answer to you.

Comment: what are you getting back from the server? What is being alerted?

Comment: You're using `.text()` and getting the text content of the <div>, not the HTML content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.text()` returns just the text content of an element.  `.html()` returns the content with the HTML intact.

```
var article_content = $("#article_content").html();
```